# Ionic2: Set all tabs inactive during first load of page

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, tabs, ionic2

I have noticed that working with Ionic2 Framework when a new page with tabs loads, the first tab is active.

What I want, is to set all tabs inactive when the page loads for the first time. I tried [selectedIndex]=-1, but it didn't work. 
My html concerning that part is:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1" tabIcon="list" tabTitle="Categories"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab (ionSelect)="scanner()" tabIcon="barcode" tabTitle="Scan"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab (ionSelect)="buffer()" tabIcon="browsers" tabTitle="History"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab (ionSelect)="cart()" tabIcon="cart" tabTitle="Shop"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Is there any attribute that I can set so I implement that kind of behaviour or am I looking for the impossible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you cannot, as the page needs to be on a tab. Selected means active

Comment: Then maybe is it possible to add a tab that is absolutely invisible to the user and use this tab as active with no specified behaviour? How I can force this tab not to occupy space?

Comment: So if all tabs are inactive, what do you wanna show for the first time? An empty screen?